# If all minors are $0$, the rank is at most $n-2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Can anyone prove/disprove the following statement?

Given a square matrix of size $n\ge2$, if all of its $(n-1)$-rowed minors are zero, then $\operatorname{rank}(A)\leq n-2$.

I'm having trouble connecting the information on the minors to what I have to prove.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A minor is already a determinant.

Comment: What about a matrix of all $1$s? It has rank $1$ for all $n$ and all $2\times 2$ minors are $0$, but If $n=1$ or $n=2$ your inequality does not hold.

Comment: I tried to correct your problem statement. Please feel free to revert the change if I've any misinterpretation.

Comment: More generally, if all $k\times k$-minors of a matrix $A$ are $0$ (for a given $k$), then $\operatorname{rank} A \leq k-1$. This is a known fact, and you can prove it faster than I can find a reference: Assume the contrary. Thus, $A$ has $k$ linearly independent rows. But the submatrix consisting of these $k$ rows must then also have rank $\geq k$, and what does this mean for its columns?

Comment: Yes, I was able to prove it for rank ≤ −1. But I can't find a way of adding the -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Post:** Show that $\text{rank}(A) \leq 2$.

This doesn't appear to be true. Consider the following matrix:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0&0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &1 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0
\end{bmatrix}$$
$A$ clearly has rank $3$. To see why all of $A$'s minors have determinant zero, just note that to create a minor, you eliminate a column and a row. But it's not possible to remove both row $1$ and row $5$ (which are both zero rows), and thus any minor must have a row of zeroes (which implies its determinant is nonzero).

**Updated Version:** Show that $\text{rank}(A) \leq n - 2$.

**Proof:** Proceed by contradiction and suppose the rank is $n - 1$ (it clearly can't be $n$, because Laplace expanding along any row or column would yield a zero determinant). If the rank is $n-1$, then it must mean that there exists some column we can remove that doesn't change the rank (because there must exist $n-1$ linearly independent columns). Assume this is the $k$th column. Upon removing this column, we have a $n \times (n-1)$ matrix, supposedly with rank $n - 1$. As this matrix has $n$ rows, it follows that we must be able to remove exactly one row without changing the rank. Let this be the $j$th row. Then we are left with a rank $n-1$ matrix that has dimensions $(n-1) \times (n-1)$, and thus it has nonzero determinant. But this matrix is exactly the $(k,j)$th minor of $A$, a contradiction.

Comment: By "quadratic" matrix, I believe the OP meant "symmetric" matrix..

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Nevertheless, the counterexample can be adjusted to maintain this property.

Comment: Yes, now no issues.

Comment: Actually, it might be that by "quadratic" matrix, the OP meant "square" matrix. But either way, your counterexample is valid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspelled the question.  Rank(A) <= n-2.     (Instead of Rank(A) <= 2).
I changed it. 
Thank for your prompt answer anyway

Comment: I see. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's well-known that row-rank = column-rank = determinantal-rank where the
determinantal rank is the size of the largest square submatrix with non-zero
determinant. Your question is an easy corollary

But let's give an *ad hoc* proof for your example. I'll prove the contrapositive,
that if $\text{rank}\, A\ge n-1$ then $A$ has a nonzero minor of size $n-1$.

As the rank of $A$ is $n$ or $n-1$, then $n-1$ rows of the matrix are linearly
independent. We can delete one row to make an $n-1$-by-$n$ matrix $B$
with linearly independent rows. It's rank is $n-1$, so $n-1$ of its columns
are linearly independent. So we can delete one column to get an $n-1$-by-$n-1$
matrix $C$ with linearly independent columns. Then $C$ is non-singular,
so $\det C\ne0$. Then $\det C$ is a non-zero minor of $A$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so much for your help!